# Stream .mov to .flv with ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

When I run the following code, the flv file is being created. But it does not play. (File size 0 kB)

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var fs = require('fs');

var write = fs.createWriteStream('output.flv');
var stream = fs.createReadStream('video.mov');

ffmpeg(stream).format('flv').pipe(write, {end: true});
```

It works when I change the code like this:

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var fs = require('fs');

var write = fs.createWriteStream('output.flv');

ffmpeg('video.mov').format('flv').pipe(write, {end: true});
```

I'm looking for a way to convert a .mov file to a .flv file using ffmpeg and createReadStream. Support.

Notes: .mov files created with iPhone / iPad

Comment: If it works when you change the code as shown, then what is the problem?

Comment: fs.createReadStream ('video.mov'); I have to read it like this. The file comes from the outside and I need to stream it.

Comment: If you call `createReadStream()` *after* `ffmpeg()...write()` (as shown in the second code you gave that works), does it work?

Comment: 2nd code is working but 1st code is not working.